# iOS Local Notification List After Notification has Fired

Tags: ios, notifications

My app runs in the background and watches for Bluetooth data. When data comes in I show a notification that the user needs to open the application so I can process the data that just came in.

I am writing to iOS 5 and later.

I make my notification using this code:

```
        UILocalNotification* alarm = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
        if (alarm) {

            alarm.fireDate = [NSDate date];
            alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
            alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
            alarm.alertBody = message;

            [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
        }
```

As I hope you can see from that code the notification fires right away.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to detect if there is already a notification on the notification bar. I have tried using:

```
        NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

        // Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.
        if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
            [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

That doesn't seem to work, however, because oldNotifications count is always 0 even though there are a ton of them on the notification bar. I assume this is because the notifications have already fired?

Basically I only want to notify the user once unless they dismiss that notification without opening the app. It would be nice if I could also increment the application badge value so the user would know how many bluetooth messages have come in. Instead I am just getting a whole new notification for each incoming message.

How do I just notify the user once and then only notify them again if they have dismissed the notification?

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that oldNotifications will always be zero because once the UILocalNotification fires, there are no more UILocalNotifications associated with your app.  That is, iOS's count of UILocalNotifications for your app will be zero.  You could make a repeating alarm that keeps firing until it is acknowledged.

Comment: Of course many users will not like being repeatedly reminded about something they decided to ignore.  I suppose it depends on how critical to your users your service is.

You could even give them a choice of what kind of notification (UILN) to fire - a repeating one for something more important, a one-off for something less.

Comment: @user856232  any update on this?

Comment: I have not spent any more time on it.